# Elastic search - search query to match any one value for a particular key

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am new to ES querying. I am try to get results based on a key that can match any value rather than one particular value. For example: key `foo` can be one among `bar, baz`. I tried this with arrays and should but ended up with wrong results or exception. What will be the correct syntax for OR case in ES. I am using ES 5.6.*

Comment: Did you get this problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways you could do this.

Depending upon the analyzer you're using, you could very much do it like this:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "foo": "bar, baz"
    }
  }
}
```

Demonstrating what it analyzes to (by default in 5.6)

```
GET /test/_analyze
{
  "field": "foo",
  "text": [
    "bar, baz"
  ]
}
```

Outputting these tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "bar",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "baz",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above example, using "bar, baz" or "bar baz" would be equivalent to search both "bar" AND "baz".

You can also group them in queries like this:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "foo": "bar"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "foo": "baz"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above would give you a scored query, requiring a match for both bar and baz in the queried documents.

You could also replace "must" with "filter", "should", or "must_not". "filter" would be unscored, should would switch you from an ANDing query to an ORing query (and you can also specify the minimum amounts of OR), or inverting the query with the "must_not"

[Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

There are more ways than just this, but this should get you started on the right track.

A "should" example requiring a hit only one of the two terms, since that was your original question:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1, 
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "foo": "bar"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "foo": "baz"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: okay let me more clear on my question. I need total 25 results. If there are total of 50 messages in ES. And 20 has value "bar" for "foo" then it should take rest 5 messages that has value "baz".

Comment: The bottom snippet I provided will give you results for any item that has "bar" OR "baz", but not be limited to the first X amount of one, then the remainder of other, If i'm interpreting your comment correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need use `bool` condition combined with `should` and `match` or `match_phrase` (You will like match_phrase as long as you know exact what you want to search)

```
GET local-signaler/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "match_phrase" : { "foo" : "bar" } },
        { "match_phrase" : { "foo" : "baz" } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler solution which avoids complex bool queries and uses the [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) array:

```
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "foo": [
                "bar",
                "baz"
            ]
        }
    }
```